# What is the terminology of this syntax in PHP

Tags: php, constants

I've been a developer for sometime now and I've recently seen the following syntax inline in PHP code

```
<<< XML...
XML;
```

It can also be be done with HTML and TXT. What is this syntax referred to as and what does it do in terms of its process

Comment: That's called a [Heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

Comment: Incidentally, it isn't related to XML, HTML, or TXT specifically. The identifier can be any arbitrary string (within the allowed character limits described in the docs) so you'll often see things like `echo <<<ASTRING .... ASTRING;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be called a [Heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

Comment: Thanks if you "include 'file.txt' between this heredoc syntax which is based on a file name would it be treated as such?

Comment: im not positive on that one but i believe it only accepts variables so if you did $file = include ('file.txt'); then did $file in it, that would work but don't quote me on it.